# Converter string em number

Tags: react-native

Como converter string em number em rect native?

Tenho uma função que recebe dois parâmetros do tipo number(2,6), porém, quando os envio de uma tela pra outra ele é recebido como string.

Como faço a conversão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funcionou pra mim assim:

`Number(string);`

Answer (score 3):

Em native:

```
var stringToNumber = "23";
var numberValue = utilsModule.convertString(stringToNumber);
```

referencia: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/utils

Em JavaScript:

```
 var number = parseInt(id.substring(indexPos) , 10 ) + 1;
```

referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713579/7920143

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: como eu faço pra importar o `utilsModule`?

Comment: Caso não esteja instalado nesse link tem a instrução:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-utils
Se está instalado nesse link tem como fazer JS e TypeScript.
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/utils

Provavelmente ele já esta instalado só fazer o import.

Answer (score 1):

Converter uma `string` para `number` em React Native é o mesmo problema de fazer isso no JavaScript, que é a linguagem usada pelo framework. Então, basta usar o `parseFloat()`:

```
parseFloat("123.45") // => 123.45 (Number)
```

Outra maneira mais "exótica" de converter é usando o sinal de mais:

```
+"123.45" // => 123.45
```